# mysql procedure subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I wrote a procedure in MYSQL, and the error message is mysql procedure subquery returns more than 1 row, i don't understand if someone can help me

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `vente`(IN `Lieu` VARCHAR(5), 
                  IN `Objet` INT, IN `Quantite` INT(3), 
                  IN `jour` INT(3), IN `Id_Mois` INT(3), 
                  IN `Annee` INT(3), IN `artisan` INT(3), 
                  IN `artisan2` VARCHAR(5), IN `deco` VARCHAR(5), 
                  IN `deco2` VARCHAR(5), IN `pouvoir` VARCHAR(5), 
                  IN `Oo` VARCHAR(5), IN `Oa` VARCHAR(5), 
                  IN `of` VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN

SET @Numventee =  (SELECT ID_vente FROM commande ORDER BY ID_vente DESC LIMIT 1 ) ;
SET @Numvente = @Numventee +1 ;

INSERT INTO commande (ID_Lieu,ID_Objet,Quantite_objet,Jour,id_Mois,Annee, id_pouvoir)
SELECT Lieu,Objet,Quantite,Jour,Id_Mois,Annee, pouvoir
LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO realiser (ID_Vente,ID_Artisan)
SELECT @Numvente,Artisan
ORDER BY ID_vente LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO realiser (ID_vente,ID_artisan)
SELECT @Numvente,artisan2 
Where  artisan2 <> 'NULL' LIMIT 1; 

INSERT INTO composer (ID_Vente,ID_Deco)
SELECT @Numvente,Deco 
Where  Deco <> 'NULL' LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO composer (ID_vente,ID_deco)
SELECT @Numvente,Deco2 
Where  Deco2 <> 'NULL' LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO couter (ID_Vente,ID_Monnaie,Quantite_Monnaie)
SELECT @Numvente,1,Oo 
Where  Oo <> 'NULL' LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO couter (ID_vente,ID_Monnaie,Quantite_Monnaie)
SELECT @Numvente,2,Oa 
Where  Oa <> 'NULL' LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO couter (ID_vente,ID_Monnaie,Quantite_Monnaie)
SELECT @Numvente,3,Of 
Where  Of <> 'NULL' LIMIT 1;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sorry i don't know how to put the code is on blocnote

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: Can you use `SELECT MAX(ID_vente) FROM commande` instead of `SELECT ID_vente FROM commande ORDER BY ID_vente DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Which line is getting that error?

Comment: Why are you using that to get the new ID? Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after the first `INSERT` to get the auto-increment ID that was assigned.

Comment: You also don't need to use `INSERT ... SELECT` when you're not selecting from another table. Use `INSERT ... VALUES()`.

Comment: @Barmar My guess is they dont have autoincrement, and in that case should fix that first.

Comment: INSERT .... VALUES() doesn't work

Comment: We have auto increment

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If they don't have auto-increment, how is the new `ID_vente` being set in the `commande` table? They're not including the variable in that `INSERT`.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, You got me there. But still dont see how that procedure will give the error OP describe in the title :/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm also not sure where the error is coming from, maybe the `LIMIT 1` clauses in `SELECT` without `FROM`. That's why I asked for the line number. But this code is so wrong I just felt like posting the correct way in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the new auto-increment ID of the row. And instead of using all those `SELECT` statements to conditionalize the inserts, use `IF` statements.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `vente`(IN `Lieu` VARCHAR(5), IN `Objet` INT, IN `Quantite` INT(3), IN `jour` INT(3), IN `Id_Mois` INT(3), IN `Annee` INT(3), IN `artisan` INT(3), IN `artisan2` VARCHAR(5), IN `deco` VARCHAR(5), IN `deco2` VARCHAR(5), IN `pouvoir` VARCHAR(5), IN `Oo` VARCHAR(5), IN `Oa` VARCHAR(5), IN `of` VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN

INSERT INTO commande (ID_Lieu,ID_Objet,Quantite_objet,Jour,id_Mois,Annee, id_pouvoir)
VALUES (Lieu,Objet,Quantite,Jour,Id_Mois,Annee, pouvoir);

SET @Numvente = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO realiser (ID_Vente,ID_Artisan)
VALUES (@Numvente,Artisan);

IF artisan2 <> 'NULL'
THEN
    INSERT INTO realiser (ID_vente,ID_artisan)
    VALUES (@Numvente,artisan2); 
END IF;

IF Deco <> 'NULL'
THEN
    INSERT INTO composer (ID_Vente,ID_Deco)
    VALUES (@Numvente,Deco);
END IF;

ID Deco2 <> 'NULL'
THEN
    INSERT INTO composer (ID_vente,ID_deco)
    VALUES (@Numvente,Deco2);
END IF;

IF Oo <> 'NULL'
THEN
    INSERT INTO couter (ID_Vente,ID_Monnaie,Quantite_Monnaie)
    VALUES (@Numvente,1,Oo);
END IF;

IF Oa <> 'NULL'
THEN
    INSERT INTO couter (ID_vente,ID_Monnaie,Quantite_Monnaie)
    VALUES (@Numvente,2,Oa);
END IF;

IF Of <> 'NULL'
THEN
    INSERT INTO couter (ID_vente,ID_Monnaie,Quantite_Monnaie)
    VALUES (@Numvente,3,Of);
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```